# How does +% damage on weapons work?

Tags: diablo-iii

Say, for example, I have a weapon with  500 DPS and for stats it says +20% damage, +120 vitality, etc. Is that +20% damage incorporated with the 500 DPS shown or is it 500dps + an additional 20% damage?

I assume it is incorporated otherwise it would make those weapons a bit too op no? Then again it is quite redundant to show +% dmg on wep if it is already added to the dps.

- Is this number already factored into the listed DPS of the weapon?
- Does this number affect anything beyond the base damage of the weapon it is on?

  - If so, how?
  - Does it affect my off-hand weapon if I'm dual wielding?
  - Is it applied before my primary stat's multipliers?

Comment: I asked a duplicate of this question [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68919/how-does-the-damage-property-on-a-weapon-work), so I edited yours to expand in scope a little bit so I could get my additional bits answered. Hope that's okay.

Answer (score 2):

Acctually, upon watching [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AEyiezB8Mpw) video the DPS in that area **IS** accounting for your bonuses on the DPS are added to the range which is then added to the total weapon DPS.

Comment: Are you sure? if you put a ruby in a weapon socket its bonus is added directly to the dps shown.

Comment: @Kappei You're right, the DPS total is accounting for the range below it and that range does include all of the buffs on the item including what you socket into it.

Answer (score 1):

The DPS on the weapon takes everything on the weapon into account EXCEPT for class specific stats that would buff your dmg. For example it won't show the added damage INT would give a wizard,  ect.