# How does the %damage property on a weapon work?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does +% damage on weapons work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68889/how-does-damage-on-weapons-work)

Now that I'm nearing level 60, I'm seeing many weapons that have +% damage on them.

- Is this number already factored into the listed DPS of the weapon?
- Does this number affect anything beyond the base damage of the weapon it is on?

  - If so, how?
  - Does it affect my off-hand weapon if I'm dual wielding?
  - Is it applied before my primary stat's multipliers?

Basically, I'm curious if I can safely ignore this property on an item when doing comparison shopping in the AH because it's already factored into the listed damage range and DPS, or if it's a value that's only represented after you equip it and see your Damage score go up.

Comment: @Emerica. Yeah, looks like basically the same question